# Group Similar Taskbar Buttons

Tags: .net, windows

Our app is made up of several Modules, and we would like to take advantage of the XP feature that would allow these to be grouped together. For example all windows in "Module A" would be grouped together, separately from windows in "Module B".

I've tried setting the AssemblyTitle attribute in the 
project's AssemblyInfo.cs file but still no title appears, only the count of 
the number of items.

Is there any way to have control over this, or is it all controlled by Windows?

This is in a WinForms application, for Windows XP.  Note that all modules are launched/hosted by a single process but what we want to do is group together all windows contained in a certain module. The Application style is SDI/MDI hybrid, just like MS Word.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Eoin says, Windows will only group taskbar buttons on a process-by-process basis. In other words, all the windows in your app will appear under one group.

The only way to get them into separate groups is to define one process for each of the groups you want. Then use [assembly: AssemblyDescription] to customise the title of each.

To my knowledge there is no way to modify these taskbar groups by hand.

Answer (score 0):

IMo that feature is about the worst feature in XP and i am so glad that  i can disable it.

But that aside, if you have the group option enabled in your taskbar then windows should do it automaticly. 
In our company we have Java applications and all different java windows are always grouped becuase they are al started by java.exe

I think that if you start allmodules with the same tool it should work

Comment: I disagree, when I'm working remotely on a smaller version of my screen (maybe 1024*768), it's useful to have more taskbar space.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fill out the AssemblyDescription property in the Assembly info file as far as i know.

```
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("MyAssemblyDescription")]
```